# Checking for non-existent optional tables

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I am using SQLAlchemy + Pyramid to operate on my database. However, there are some optional tables which are not always expected to be present in the DB. So while querying them I try to catch such cases with the `NoSuchTableError`

```
try:
    x = session.query(ABC.name.label('sig_name'),func.count('*').label('count_')).join(DEF).join(MNO).filter(MNO.relevance >= relevance_threshold).group_by(DEF.signature).order_by(desc('count_')).all()[:val]
except NoSuchTableError:
    x = [-1,]
```

But on executing this statement, I get a ProgrammingError

```
ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) (1146, "Table 'db.mno' doesn't exist")
```

Why does SQLAlchemy raise the more general ProgrammingError instead of the more specific NoSuchTableError? And if this is indeed expected behaviour, how do I ensure the app displays correct information depending on whether tables are present/absent?

**EDIT1**

Since this is part of my webapp, the model of DB is in `models.py` (under my pyramid webapp). I do have a setting in my .ini file that asks user to select whether additional tables are available or not. But not trusting the user, I want to be able to check for myself (in the views) whether table exists or not. The contentious table is something like (in `models.py`)

```
class MNO(Base):
    __tablename__="mno"
    id=Column(Integer,primary_key=True,autoincrement=True)
    sid=Column(Integer)
    cid=Column(mysql.MSInteger(unsigned=True))
    affectability=Column(Integer)
    cvss_base=Column(Float)
    relevance=Column(Float)
    __table_args__=(ForeignKeyConstraint(['sid','cid',],['def.sid','def.cid',]),UniqueConstraint('sid','cid'),)
```

How and Where should the check be made so that a variable can be set (preferably during app setup) which tells me whether the tables are present or not?

Note: In this case I would have to try if...else rather than 'ask for forgiveness'

Comment: added another part to my answer to try to deal with your new question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [sqlalchemy](http://modular.math.washington.edu/home/wstein/www/home/dfdeshom/custom/sage/local/doc/SQLAlchemy-0.4.3/sqlalchemy_exceptions.html#docstrings_sqlalchemy.exceptions_NoSuchTableError) docs, a `NoSuchTableError` is only thrown when "SQLAlchemy [is] asked to load a table's definition from the database, but the table doesn't exist."  You could try loading a table's definition, catching the error there, and doing your query otherwise.

If you want to do things via "asking for forgiveness":

```
try:
    table = Table(table_name, MetaData(engine)) 
except NoSuchTableError:
    pass
```

Alternatively, you could just check whether the table exists:

**Edit:**

Better yet, why don't you use the [has_table method](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/core/internals.html?highlight=has_table#sqlalchemy.engine.base.Dialect.has_table):

```
if engine.dialect.has_table(connection, table_name):
    #do your crazy query
```

---

Why don't you use [Inspector](http://%5Bhttp://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/core/schema.html?highlight=inspector#sqlalchemy.engine.reflection.Inspector%5D) to grab the table names first?

Maybe something like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.engine import reflection
#whatever code you already have
engine = create_engine('...')
insp = reflection.Inspector.from_engine(engine)
table_name = 'foo'
table_names = insp.get_table_names()
if table_name in table_names:
    x = session.query(ABC.name.label('sig_name'),func.count('*').label('count_')).join(DEF).join(MNO).filter(MNO.relevance >= relevance_threshold).group_by(DEF.signature).order_by(desc('count_')).all()[:val]
```

Comment: I was trying to be true to python's lexicon [EAFP] (http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-eafp) ;).... will try one of these

Comment: Nope the object gets created without any exception even when table is not present

Comment: @RedBaron In that case why don't you just put an `if engine.dialect.has_table(connection, table_name):
` right before line 1146 cause it looks like that's where your error is.

Comment: In that case I would be explicitly checking the table 'mno'. I was hoping for a more elegant solution that lets me see the status of the table through the class MNO itself. Anyways, I think it is better to read the setting value and define the model accordingly and also checking for the setting value before querying. It will not be 'ask for forgiveness' but it would work

Comment: Finally I used has_table() during my db initialization phase in my web-app and based on whether it returns True or False, I set the appropriate setting variable and then use that variable throughout my app to fire one or the other query.